# Loop for create multiple dataframe based on one dataframe and parse each new dataframe on each excel sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXZy4.png)

Dear all attached small view on my dataframe (55437,7), that contain many INDICATOR_ID for many countries.
I would like to loop for create many dataframe based on each INDICATOR_ID (column) value and export each news dataframe on each excel sheet (same workbook).

regards

at the end have a workbook that cointain each indicators on each excel sheet.

Click on enter image description here to view dataframe attached.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you unable to do? What is your expected result? “Show/tell me how to solve this coding problem” [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). We expect you to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a *specific* question about your technique.

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability to others as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/).

Comment: I would like to parse each  indicators (57 in total) in one excel sheets separaltly (57 sheets). to conclude create multiple dataframe based in selected each values on Indicators_DCS.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use groupby like this:

```
groups = df.groupby('INDICATOR_ID')
sub_dataframes = [groups.get_group(indicator) for indicator in groups.groups]
```